# Ignoring a ValueError and returning 1 when no input is given

Tags: python

I am creating a program to find the LCM of two numbers. I want to return 1 when no input is given, but instead I end up with a ValueError as no integer input is given. I know that you can use Try and Except to ignore the ValueError, but I'm not exactly sure how you use them. This is my complete code:

```
def lcm(number1,number2):
    if number1>number2:
        largernumber= number1
    else:
        largernumber=number2
    multiple=largernumber
    
        
    while True:
        if largernumber%number1==0 and largernumber%number2==0:
            print("The LCM is", largernumber)
            break
        else:
            largernumber=largernumber+multiple
        
number1=int(input("Please enter number 1: "))
number2=int(input("Please enter number 2: "))
if number1==0 or number2==0:
    print("0")
else:
    lcm(number1,number2)
```

Comment: This is a very slow way to implement lcm.  All you need is `x*y//math.gcd(x,y)`.  That's it.  That's lcm.  Although I usually do `(x//math.gcd(x,y))*y` to keep the intermediate values smaller.  And you do need to check for a zero gcd and handle that case specially.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it like this

```
def lcm(number1,number2):
    if number1>number2:
        largernumber= number1
    else:
        largernumber=number2
    multiple=largernumber
    
        
    while True:
        if largernumber%number1==0 and largernumber%number2==0:
            print("The LCM is", largernumber)
            break
        else:
            largernumber=largernumber+multiple
try:
    number1=int(input("Please enter number 1: "))
    number2=int(input("Please enter number 2: "))
    if number1==0 or number2==0:
        print("0")
    else:
        lcm(number1,number2) 
except:
    print(1)
```